# CKEditor List Number Special character problem

Tags: ckeditor

Trying to add special character to CKEditor lists.
ex:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSnSi.png)

in this list i cant add 'ç' character between c and d. how can i fix this problem